тг бот, не робатает кнопка перехода с "турники/элементы"
import telebot
from telebot import types
import webbrowser
bot = telebot.TeleBot('код')



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id )

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Турники', callback_data='t' ))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Брусья', callback_data='b'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'<b>Здравствуйте</b>, {message.from_user.first_name} , это бот',  parse_mode='html' , reply_markup=markup)
    




@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == 't':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Упражнения', callback_data='ypdr' ))
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Элементы', callback_data='afdu'))
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Выходы', callback_data='vidh'))
        bot.edit_message_text('<b>Отлично, теперь выберете: </b> \n \n Упражнения \n Элементы \n Выходы' , callback.message.chat.id , callback.message.message_id ,  parse_mode='html' , reply_markup=markup  )
        
    if callback.data == 'b':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Упражнения', callback_data='yprb' ))
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Элементы', callback_data='aldb'))
        bot.edit_message_text('Отлично, теперь выберете:' , callback.message.chat.id , callback.message.message_id  , reply_markup=markup )






 #это не работает, ниже (это переход с турники на элементы)

   @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)       
    def callback_message(callback): 
        if callback.data == 'afdu':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Подъём переворотом', callback_data='podiomsperev' 
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Перышко', callback_data='perishko'))
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('склепка', callback_data='sklepka' ))
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('солнышко', callback_data='solnishko' ))
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(' Финский подъем', callback_data='finsk'))
            bot.edit_message_text('Отлично, теперь выберете:' , callback.message.chat.id , callback.message.message_id  , reply_markup=markup )







bot.polling(none_stop=True)


потому, что у вас в первом хэндлере func=lambda callback: True, которая перехватывает все колбэки и до второго хэндлера у вас сообщения никогда не дойдут

А что тогда мне написать за место  func=lambda callback: True что бы зароботал 2 хэндлер и в дальнейшем и 3 хэндлер?

вместо func=lambda callback: True используйте func=lambda callback: callback.data == "ypdr" и т.д.

Сделал но все ровно не работает

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data == "ypdr")
def callback_message(callback):
if callback.data == 'ypdr':
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Подъём переворотом', callback_data='podiomsperev' ))
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Перышко', callback_data='perishko'))
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('склепка', callback_data='sklepka' ))

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data == "t" or "b")
def callback_message(callback):
if callback.data == 't':
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Упражнения', callback_data='ypdr' ))
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Элементы', callback_data='afdu'))
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Выходы', callback_data='vidh'))

О я сам смог сделать просто добавил afdu в @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True) (самое начало ) и оно заработало. Но все равно спасибо за попытку мне помочь и за выделенное время на это)
